# Kendo grid asp.net MVC create custom column

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

I try to create grid using kendo UI core and Asp.net Mvc, I have problem when I create a custom template column include text input with image per cell, I defined the client template and editor template with the required html to be generated for every cell in the specific column.

It’s working good till I add new row it removes all of old row’s values even it does not go to server where I use batch editing grid.
I’ve tried to set only editor template without client template then I got that I can’t click on Image in editor template, because when I click on it my editor template removed from cell and converted to html td cell.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RjUe.png)

## This is my code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ItemsModel>().Name("Grid").Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.Id).ClientTemplate("<input type='text'/><img src='/Content/Images/image.gif' onclick= 'OpenPopup(this)' />").EditorTemplateName("IdEditor");
            columns.Bound(p => p.Price).ClientTemplate("<input type='text' />").EditorTemplateName("Price");
            columns.Bound(p => p.Qty);
            columns.Bound(p => p.TotalPrice);
            columns.Command(command => command.Destroy());
        })
    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
    {
        toolbar.Create();
        toolbar.Save();
    })
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .Pageable()
    .Navigatable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Batch(false)
        .PageSize(20)
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Field(p => p.Id).Editable(false);
                model.Field(p => p.Price).Editable(false);
                model.Id(p => p.Id);
            })
        .Create("Editing_Create", "Test")
            .Read("Editing_Read", "Test")
            .Update("Editing_Update", "Test")
            .Destroy("Editing_Destroy", "Test")))
```